# Sub query brain freeze

Tags: sql, subquery

Its been a while since I've done sub queries and for the life of me I cant see whats wrong with my query.

The error message I get when executing is:

```
ORA-00904: "SUB"."PRO_REFNO": invalid identifier
```

This is my query. I'm obviously doing something wrong but I just cant see it.

```
SELECT
 prop.PRO_ADR_1_LINE,
 ele.POE_START_DATE,
 ele.POE_ELEMENT_DESCR,
 ele.POE_VALUE,
 ele.POE_ATTRIBUTE,
 ele.POE_FURTHER_ATTRIBUTE,
 ele.POE_FURTHER_ATTRIBUTE_DESCR,
 prop.PRO_SCHEME,
 prop.PRO_SCHEME_DESCR,
 GEO.GEO_BUS_UNIT,
 GEO.GEO_REGION,
 GEO.GEO_REGION_DESCR,
 prop.PRO_NEIGHBOURHOOD_DESCR
 --sub.pro_refno

FROM property prop 
--inner join



left join GEO on prop.PRO_GEO_PATCH=GEO.GEO_PATCH
left join PROPERTY_OTHER_ELEMENT ele on ele.POE_PRO_REFNO =prop.PRO_REFNO
inner join(
SELECT
property.PRO_SCHEME,
count(distinct property.PRO_REFNO)
FROM
PROPERTY
WHERE
property.pro_type  =  'P'
GROUP BY
property.PRO_SCHEME
)sub
on sub.pro_refno = prop.PRO_REFNO
where
  ele.POE_START_DATE  BETWEEN '01-APR-2016'  AND  sysdate
  AND
  ele.POE_ELEMENT  LIKE  'EST%'
  AND
  ele.POE_ELEMENT_DESCR  <>  'Estate Walkabout - Would you live in this neighbourhood ?'
  AND
  ele.POE_VALUE  IN  ( '1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10'  )
```

Both the outer query and sub query run fine separately. Like I said its been a while so I'm guessing its something stupid I've done/not done.

Thanks

Adam

Comment: Your are joining `pro_refno`, but the subquery does not return such a value.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't give a name to the aggregate column:

```
inner join(
SELECT
property.PRO_SCHEME,
count(distinct property.PRO_REFNO) -- No name!!!
FROM
PROPERTY
WHERE
property.pro_type  =  'P'
GROUP BY
property.PRO_SCHEME
)sub
on sub.pro_refno = prop.PRO_REFNO
```

Change that to:

```
inner join(
SELECT
property.PRO_SCHEME,
count(distinct property.PRO_REFNO) As PRO_REFNO
FROM
PROPERTY
WHERE
property.pro_type  =  'P'
GROUP BY
property.PRO_SCHEME
)sub
on sub.pro_refno = prop.PRO_REFNO
```

Answer (score 0):

Your subquery doesn't select PRO_REFNO, so the outer query cannot match it in the JOIN predicate. Try this for the subquery:

```
SELECT
    property.PRO_SCHEME,
    property.PRO_REFNO,
    count(distinct property.PRO_REFNO)
FROM PROPERTY
WHERE property.pro_type = 'P'
GROUP BY
property.PRO_SCHEME,
property.PRO_REFNO
```

Also, your COUNT(DISTINCT ...) isn't given an alias, which you'll need if it's ever going to be used in the outer select.